# Square equivalent of $circ(r)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, special-functions

I would like to know if there is a similar function to

$$circ(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=1 , 0\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq 1$$

but with a square domain $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$.

If yes, which is its fourier transform?

I know that $\mathscr{F}circ(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=\frac{J_1(2\pi\sqrt{\xi_x^2+\xi_y^2})}{\sqrt{\xi_x^2+\xi_y^2}}$

Thanks!

Comment: It's simpler, because the whole situation is now a cartesian product. The Fourier transform will be a product of ${\rm sinc}$ functions, which are elementary. You can do the integrals yourself.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I don't see why it should the product of sinc functions. The fourier transform of a cartesian product is just the product of the fourier transforms?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter got it. Thanks!!